# ffmpeg-cli-wrapper: Unable to merge image and audio (mp3) input to an video output (mp4)

Tags: ffmpeg

I want to combine an image and an audio file to create a video output.
I'm able to do it from command line:
ffmpeg -loop 1 -i /tmp/image.jpeg -i /tmp/audiot.mp3 -vf 'scale=320:trunc(ow/a/2)*2' -acodec libvo_aacenc -b:a 192k -shortest /tmp/output.mp4

But when I'm trying to implement the same behavior using ffmpeg-cli-wrapper java, the progam just keeps running indefinitely.
[Raised issue on GitHub too.](https://github.com/bramp/ffmpeg-cli-wrapper/issues/112)

I couldn't find any example for this online. If someone knows how to implement this behavior using the same or any other framework, please let me know.
Here is my sample test java program.

```
        FFmpeg ffmpeg = new FFmpeg("/usr/bin/ffmpeg/ffmpeg");
        FFprobe ffprobe = new FFprobe("/usr/bin/ffprobe");


        FFmpegBuilder builder = new FFmpegBuilder()

                .setInput("/tmp/image.jpeg")// Filename, or a FFmpegProbeResult  
                .addInput("/tmp/audio.mp3")
                .addExtraArgs("-loop","1")

                  .overrideOutputFiles(true) // Override the output if it exists

                  .addOutput("/tmp/output.mp4")   // Filename for the destination
                    .setFormat("mp4")        // Format is inferred from filename, or can be set
                    //.setTargetSize(250_000)  // Aim for a 250KB file

                    //.disableSubtitle()       // No subtiles

                    //.setAudioChannels(1)         // Mono audio
                    .setAudioCodec("aac")        // using the aac codec
                    .setAudioSampleRate(48_000)  // at 48KHz
                    .setAudioBitRate(32768)      // at 32 kbit/s

                    .setVideoCodec("libx264")     // Video using x264
                    .setVideoFrameRate(24, 1)     // at 24 frames per second
                    .setVideoResolution(640, 480) // at 640x480 resolution
                    //.setComplexVideoFilter("scale=320:trunc(ow/a/2)*2")

                    .setStrict(FFmpegBuilder.Strict.EXPERIMENTAL) // Allow FFmpeg to use experimental specs
                    .done();

                FFmpegExecutor executor = new FFmpegExecutor(ffmpeg, ffprobe);

                // Run a one-pass encode
                executor.createJob(builder).run();
```

Answer (score 0):

Your example command and the command in the code appear to be different.

Your image input is looping continuously using the `-loop 1` input option (or at least I'm assuming it is being applied, but hard to tell), but your code is missing the `-shortest` output option causing the command to run indefinitely.